# SAP BusinessObjects custom authentication

Tags: authentication, business-objects

We're currently evaluating SAP BusinessObjects XI 3 for a front end reporting solution, but I'm not happy that we will need to create a new set of logins that will be managed independently from our existing website. We have an authentication API that our various applications all hook into, so we effectively get single sign on, and single account management.

Is there a way to write a custom authentication plugin for SAP BOE 3?

I've googled for information and have come up empty handed. Links to documents would be handy also.

Comment: What's your environment? Virtually certain a recent prior version of BO/CR enterprise-level products supported AD-based logins under Windows Server...

Comment: I'm aware of the AD based auth - but I want to write my own custom authenticator. For more information though, it's running on redhat/tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that we use for this problem is to have a seperate password management page built into the HR space that will change all the user's passwords to the same thing. So there is one input for username and pass that changes the global password for a user and then it runs through and changes all the different SAP ones that are needed.

Not really the answer you are looking for, but it is somewhat of a solution.

Comment: Forgive me, but I know next to nothing about SAP, and BOE is the only SAP product that we're running. Is there any documentation related to the solution you use, so I might evaluate it fully?